# Redirect DNS requests for 8.8.8.8 to a local DNS inside a LAN

Tags: domain-name-system, ip, local-area-network, redirection

I have a local network (10.0.0.0/24) with a gateway (I'll call it G, IP 10.0.0.1), a device (I'll call it N, IP 10.0.0.31) making DNS requests directly to 8.8.8.8 completely ignoring DHCP setting for DNS, and another device running my DNS server (I'll call it D, IP 10.0.0.2). Both G and D run Linux and I can completely alter their configuration whatever I want. Instead, I can't alter N's behaviour in any way, except from assigning it a different IP address through DHCP.

Now, I'd like to redirect DNS requests coming from N for 8.8.8.8 to D, so D can process that requests and provide DNS results back to N, without N noticing anything. I think that, since the local network and its gateway are under my complete control and since there is no SSL or cryptografy involved with DNS, this should be feasible.

So, how can I accomplish this?

Comment: Using iptables apply DNAT on G to packets going to 8.8.8.8 port 53 (both tcp and udp), rewrite destination ip to D

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for your comment. Please, can you provide a more detailed answer? The fact is that I actually tried to do this but I must be doing something wrong because, while the DNAT on G works fine, the iptables' rewriting rules on D are never matched; so N receives DNS results from D that it never asked for and discard them, while it never receives the awaited results from 8.8.8.8.

Comment: Yeah didn't think of that, return packets would not pass through G. Would be simpler if D and G were the same machine. The route somehow (on G, using, not sure what works, iptables or ip rules and custom routing tables) dns packets to D and do the DNAT there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remeber `8.8.8.8` is an anycast address.  You can basically do the exactly same thing Google does for maintaining one of their boxes that serve the `8.8.8.8` traffic.

Assign the IP address `8.8.8.8` as an additional address on the DNS server, and Possibly add a route if necessary directing `8.8.8.8/32` directing the traffic to your that DNS server.

Comment: Thanks. It was a brilliant solution and worked like a charm.

Comment: hello, can you please elaborate more exactly how you handled this situation? In my case the local dns server (acrylic dns proxy to cloudflare's DOH) and the app attempting to bypass my dns (towards 8.8.8.8) are on the same device (windows). I know 6 years have passed on this thread, but maybe you can help me out :) thanks!